# How can I load a numerical value from a saved file instead of hard coding coefficients?

Tags: r, io

How to load a number from a save or dump file? Here's my code example so far:

```
t = lm(cars$dist~cars$speed)# build linear regression and get coefficients. 
car_speed = seq(cars$speed)
D.hat = -17.579 + 3.932 * car_speed
```

Comment: Are you looking for `coef(lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars))` ? respective `D.hat <- predict(lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars))`

Comment: Yeah, I got the coefficients, but how to save them into a file and load them to calculate the D.hat?

Comment: You save the coefficients in a vector: `m <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars); b <-  coef(m); D.hat <- b[1] + b[2]*car_speed` BTW: what are you doing with `seq(cars$speed)` ? Is it really that what you want? Eventually you want `D.hat <- predict(m, newdata=data.frame(speed=1:50))`

Comment: thx!!!!  I got it.